# Can't seem to get my div's label to overflow the way I want it to

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsfiddle

I have this HTML:

```
<div id="contentPanelHeading" class="div">
    <label id="originalNameLabel" class="label">ThisIsAReallyLongBlockOfTextThatWillOverflowTheParentDiv</label>
</div>
```

This is my CSS:

```
.div
{
    background-color: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

An example JSFiddle is available [here](https://jsfiddle.net/54qef5fb/).

How can I make my text overflow into the block, as follows:

```
|BigWordsShould|
|BeAlignedLikeT|
|hisInsideMyDiv|
|AndOnlyOverflo|
|wGoingDownWard|
 sLikeThis,Outs
 isdeOfTheDivFr
 omTheBottom
```

Note how the letters overflow the div going down and how a large word such as this gets broken down. How can I get it to do this? I have tried a bunch of different tricks I looked up but none seemed to work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need to specify the css properity word-wrap:

```
.label
{
  word-wrap: break-word; 
 }
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/54qef5fb/1/)

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks! Exactly what I needed! I dunno why this didn't come up first in my searching.